# Order of resistor/capacitor in bandpass/highpass filter

Tags: filter

Is there any particular reason to prefer one of these filter designs over the other? Theoretically, they are the same. Practically, does changing the order of the resistor and capacitor have any effect (except, perhaps, on physical layout)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a "order of a resistor"? Do you mean "sequence"? In this case, no - both circuits are equal.

Comment: Look at the two diagrams. They are mostly the same, except for the resistor and capacitor at the front are exchanged.

Comment: Obviously, yes. But - what is your problem? In any  case, the circuit is the worst bandpass we can imagine (quality factor 0.5 at maximum)

Comment: @Andy - you're not allowed to decompile the supply rails except for purposes of interfacing to them - it's in the license!

Comment: @briandrummond darn the stupid spell checker on my android phone LOL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in certain circumstances there is a difference between the two.

Consider the case where the amplifier operates in large electric fields, and the impedances are high (e.g. megohms). Then, every millimetre of wire or PCB track between the highest impedance components and the "virtual earth" (negative input) is an antenna picking up noise.

So place the highest impedance component adjacent to the opamp and the lower impedance one further out to minimise the area and minimise interference.

Then you have to ask which of R1 and C1 is the higher impedance component...
I can't answer that without knowing the context; but a couple of examples may help.

1) Lots of low frequency interference at say 50 or 60Hz: comparing R and Xc you probably find the capacitor is the high impedance component, and the resistor placement is less critical.

2) High frequency interference (e.g. in a switch mode power supply or RF transmitter) . Xc is small, and R is the high impedance component.

3) Special case of 2) The amplifier has a lot of gain at HF and tends to form an unintended UHF oscillator : introduce a new resistor between the circuit node and -Vin, as close to -Vin as possible. This resistor is small (a few hundred ohms maybe) and is known as a base stopper (or grid stopper, or gate stopper, depending on the amplifier!)

But there are many cases where it simply doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you! THIS is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is implied on any circuit diagram that the "wires" or lines on the diagram are not real wires, but just indicate that the components are connected, and that their physical position is not important (including the sequence)

So the simple answer is: The circuits are identical (except for the component numbering, and the lack of power supply as @Andy-aka commented.

If the physical position or any other construction details are important, this should be annotated on the circuit diagram.

If you want to represent stray inductance, capacitance, external electrical fields etc. because that's the objective of the circuit diagram, rather show these **as** inductors, capacitors, signal sources  etc. on the diagram. If that's what you want to highlight by the diagram.

Comment: I'm a little frustrated that so many people commented without taking the time to understand my question. The circuits are, in fact, not identical.

Comment: Hi @BigEndian, I (wrongly) assumed from your question that you _weren't_ interested in the effects of physical layout (especially the part "except, perhaps, on physical layout"), which of course are important as BrianDrummond has nicely explained.

Comment: When track impedances and induced voltages can be ignored, components in series are calculated by adding their impedances (i.e. complex resistances). Since the effect of adding two numbers (scalars or vectors) is the same if the numbers are reversed, the circuits *(ignoring stray effects mentioned)* are in fact identical. 2+7 = 7+2. Also (e.g. for R + C) 5+3i = 3i+5. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Series_combination and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Parallel_combination